# Oracle Golden gate version using shell scrip

Tags: linux, shell-scripting, oracle-11g

I am trying to grep the Oracle golden gate from a remote machine, But along with version it is giving some error details also, How do I resolve it ?

```
user@serverhost:/dbei > echo  <golgengate install path>/ggsci | ssh gger@payhlc203 | grep "Version"

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
Version 11.2.1.0.3 14400833 OGGCORE_11.2.1.0.3_PLATFORMS_120823.1258_FBO
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the -T option to ssh;

> -T      Disable pseudo-tty allocation.

from the manpage.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you disable pseudo-tty allocation (`-T` option), you may still get the `Invalid argument` error.

It looks like `ggsci` is an interactive program that expects some input. You might try something like this instead:

```
echo | ssh gger@payhlc203 /path/to/goldengate/ggsci | grep Version
```

Failing that, you can always get rid of the extraneous output by redirecting `stderr`, eg:

```
echo | ssh gger@payhlc203 /path/to/goldengate/ggsci 2>/dev/null | grep Version
```